# SelectCount by Three options ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a count for the GetUsers but I have 3 different calculations either by alpha, search and byEmail parameters what can I do in this situation for my ObjectDataSource SelectCount method

```
public class Users
{
    public IList<MembershipUser> GetUsers(string alpha, string search, bool byEmail, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
    {
        IList<MembershipUser> users = null;

        if (alpha != null && search == null)
        {
            users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha) == true).ToList();
        }
        else if (search != null && !byEmail)
        {
            users = Membership.FindUsersByName(search).Cast<MembershipUser>().Skip(maximumRows * startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            users = Membership.FindUsersByEmail(search).Cast<MembershipUser>().Skip(maximumRows * startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }

        return users;

    }

    public int GetUserCount()
    {

    }
```

Updated C#:

```
    public IEnumerable<MembershipUser> GetUsers(string alpha, string searchBy, string searchText, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();

        if (alpha != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
        {
            users = users
                .Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .Skip(maximumRows * startRowIndex)
                .Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }
        else if (searchBy == "User Name" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.UserName == searchText)
                .Skip(maximumRows * startRowIndex)
                .Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }
        else if (searchBy == "Email" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.Email == searchText)
                .Skip(maximumRows * startRowIndex)
                .Take(maximumRows).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            users = null;
        }

        return users;

    }
```

Comment: *fix that for me* are generally bad words in this community. We can *help* **you** fix your problem but the expectation that we will fix anything for you is a bad one.

Comment: @M.Babcock sorry i won't put it like that next time but my real issue is when I need to do a count how do i determine which count to select.

Comment: That almost sounds like a business rule that you should be asking your designer. We don't know your data so we could only speculate.

Comment: The data is the MembershipUser and Im needing a count by a users selection thats passed in either by Membership.FindUsersByName, Membership.FindUsersByEmail or Membership.GetAllUsers() what can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
public int GetUserCount(string alpha, string search, bool byEmail, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();

    if (alpha != null && search == null)
    {
        users = users.Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith(alpha) == true);
    }
    else if (search != null && !byEmail)
    {
        users = users.FindUsersByName(search).Cast<MembershipUser>();
    }
    else
    {
        users = users.FindUsersByEmail(search);
    }

    return users.Count();
}
```

I would be more comfortable with this approach if `FindUsersByName` and `FindUsersByEmail` returned objects related to `IEnumerable<T>` so you could depend on the lazy nature of LINQ, but in this case it doesn't matter since you're doing a count. I'd recommend some form of `Select` to limit the fields being queried over, but in your second two cases, they'll pull all results anyway so it would be without benefit 2/3 possible situations. If you find that more often than not the query is done by `UserName` then it would probably be worth adding there.

Comment: I've updated my c# and I just went ahead and turned it into IEnumerable<T> without looking at you're answer. is this what you meant in you're comment. I didn't use a select i used a where statment

Comment: Generally, yes. The benefit of using a `Select` in this case would be to reduce the number of fields brought back from the database (which would make it slightly more efficient). I think it would only be of benefit in the first if though since `FindUsersByName` will return your whole objects anyway.

Comment: The only fields I need is username but when I need todo a delete it needs the MembershipUser class object when I do the DataItem for my LinkButton commandArgument on ItemDataBound in my ListView. I've never done a Select() statement before to create a anonymous object how do you do that i might have it wrong anonymous object can you give me an example in a select statment update code